# ¿Se tienen que declarar como variables los parámetros de una función?

Tags: javascript, funciones

estoy con JavaScript y me queda la duda de si los parámetros de las funciones se tienen que declarar previamente como variables. Yo lo tengo así:

```
function multiplicar (valor1,valor2) {
  return valor1 + valor2;
}

let guardaResultado = multiplicar(10,10);

document.write("El valor de la multiplicación es: " + guardaResultado);
```

Funciona correctamente, pero me pregunto si es mala práctica no declarar antes las variables valor1 y valor2. Así:

```
let valor1;
let valor2;

function multiplicar (valor1,valor2) {
  return valor1 + valor2;
}

let guardaResultado = multiplicar(10,10);

document.write("El valor de la multiplicación es: " + guardaResultado);
```

¿Cuál de las dos es mejor? ¿Son válidas las dos?

Comment: No, no necesitas declarar los parámetros como variables. Son dos cosas totalmente diferentes y te dará problemas si lo haces. Los parámetros están siempre disponibles **SOLO *DENTRO*** de la función, las variables pueden estar disponibles tanto dentro como fuera (dependerá del *scope* de la función). Así que no te preocupes, lo estás haciendo bien al no declararlos, puesto que en realidad no estarías declarando los parámetros... si no otras variables **DIFERENTES** que se llaman igual.

Comment: No, tal como te han comentado, no es necesario. Los parámetros son parte de la declaración de la función, por lo cual, al declarar la función, todos sus parámetros quedan automáticamente declarados y forman parte del ámbito (`scope`) interno de esa función. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, ahora tiene todo el sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando llamas a una función con parámetros, estás declarando e inicializando (o no) las variables, todo lo que tengas fuera del alcance de la función no importará si lo vuelves a declarar.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
const C = 1;

function a(C) {
    console.log(C);
}

a(2);
```

Esto va a devolver 2, y observa que se trata de una constante!! Si tienes algunas bases mínimas en desarrollo, sabrás que usando la lógica que planteas, esto no tiene sentido.

Así que ahora, quita la primera línea y vuelve a correr el código, funcionará exactamente igual.